# How to remove hover state when the element moves

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I have this example:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="bp"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VKwjD/20/

if you hover the same square, his color changes; if you click, the parent size changes so the square move.

My problem is: If you don't move your mouse after the click, the square stays in the hover state... Why ?
It's possible to remove this state after the click? without moving the mouse...

Thank you for your help

Comment: Its a known issue with browsers like IE, you cannot reproduce the same in latest versions of chrome.

Comment: Right, hover state won't change until the mouse moves as the hover state is an event attached to the mouse move in IE

Comment: is it problem in IE only? I don't see any problem in firefox, chrome.

Comment: Right, IE problem.  I'd change the color using jQuery mouseenter/mouseleave

Comment: I have this problem on chrome and safari mac osx too

Answer (score -2):

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="bp" id="bp"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    background: #FF0000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}    
.container.hide {
    width: 50px; 
}        
.bp {
    background: #00FFFF;
    width: 30px;
    height:30px;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    position:absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
}    
.bp:hover{
    background: #0000FF!important;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.bp').click(function() {        
        if($('.container').hasClass('hide')) {
            $('.container').removeClass('hide');
            var l1 = document.getElementById('bp');
            l1.style.background = '#00FFFF';            
        }
        else {
            $('.container').addClass('hide');
            var l1 = document.getElementById('bp');
            l1.style.background = '#0000FF';
        }
    });        
});
```

Comment: I have added a **id="bp"** and provided some CSS using javaScript by defining some variable.

Comment: Does not answer question.